# What should i use i if need a custom converter when using @RequestParam?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I if have a method signature as follows

```
public void deposit(@RequestParam("accountId") Integer accountId, 
                    @RequestParam("amount") BigDecimal amount) {...}
```

And because i have a locale specific decimal value **which needs to be converted to a BigDecimal**, is there some annotation which allows me to set up incoming data such as @Decimal("###.###,##") or something else ???

Comment: Consider using String parameter types for request parameters.  If you perform the number conversion in your code, you get to catch the NumberFormatException that is thrown for incorrectly formatted parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring 3 has [`@NumberFormat`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/NumberFormat.html) annotation:

```
public void deposit(@RequestParam("accountId") Integer accountId,  
    @RequestParam("amount") @NumberFormat(pattern = "###.###,##") BigDecimal amount) 
{...}
```

You need `<mvc:annotation-driven>` to enable it.

**See also:**

- [Spring MVC 3 Showcase](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/22/spring-mvc-3-showcase/)

Comment: Nice one (+1) Do you know if i can register **a global converter** to avoid @NumberFormat annotation ???

Comment: @Arthur: Perhaps you can install a custom formatter for `BigDecimal` by customizing `FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean`, see how it's done in `mvc-showcase`.

Answer (score 2):

More generically you can register a custom converter with the [ConversionServiceFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert-Spring-config). Once you do that you will need to [add a custom web binding initializer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-webdatabinder) to your handler adapter

Example Config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
          <property name="conversionService" ref="conversionService"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="myCustomConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```